# Using a calculated field at table level

Tags: ms-access

After Googling for a while I was wondering about the use of a calculated field at table level. I know its a big No,No but I wanted to use it as a method of preventing duplicates. For Example, I have a Payroll table and I wanted to concatenate the Employee ID field and the Work Day field. So during payroll entry some code can lookup that field to alert if the record exist.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your data entry is through a properly managed form and not a form directly linked to the table you don't need the lookup to be on a single field, you can check for duplicates that match multiple criteria.

Simple example:

```
If Nz(DLookup("MyTableID","MyTableName","EmployeeID=" & Me.EmployeeID & " AND WorkDay=#" & Me.WorkDay & "#"),0)=0 Then
    [Handle Add Record to Table]
  Else
    [Handle duplicate exists]
  End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Calculated fields cannot be indexed, so any lookup on a calculated field will probably result in a table scan. You'd probably be better off to create a unique index on the two columns to prevent duplicates.